# Extended WPF Toolkit - Resizing a childwindow

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I´m using the librariay Extended WPF Toolkit

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Is it possible to resize a ChildWindow like a ordinary Window?

The documentation shows some properties that seem to be related, but they are not accessible via xaml. https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow

This is the example that I´m trying:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
         xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <xctk:WindowContainer>
        <xctk:ChildWindow WindowBackground="Blue"
                    Left="75"
                    Top="50"
                    Width="275"
                    Height="125"
                    WindowState="Open" Canvas.Top="52">
            <TextBlock Text="This is a Child Window" Padding="10"/>
        </xctk:ChildWindow>
    </xctk:WindowContainer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading this right, are you just referring to [ResizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) wherein you can just set `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip` ?

Comment: I´m trying to make "resizeable" the ChildWindow object.. the documentation tells that this object also has a property named "ResizeMode", but I can´t find how to use it in the xaml code

Comment: You would just declare it up with the namespaces of the window, or is that the part not working for you?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, I mean, the ResizeMode property is present in the <Window> object, but it is not in the <xctk:ChildWindow>, even though the documentation says that it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the Resize functionality is only available in the **Plus Edition** of the software, the documentation can be found at the link below.

Based on the link you provided, it looks like you are using the same version as I am, which is the free one.

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow%20Plus

Kind of disappointing, we don't utilize the toolkit enough to warrant the cost.

Comment: Have you tried [WindowContainer](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WindowContainer)? (From docs: "Many actions performed on its children are managed by the WindowContainer (movement and positioning, resizing...")